# RecyclerView scrolling makes my items disappeared

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-adapter

I have `RecyclerView` with `Adapter`. Next to the `RecyclerView` is `Button` which will open up new `Activity` (form like layout) to create new item to this `RecyclerView`. As I create this item, I call methods below to refresh my data. Data are there and it works as intended. I have implemented `LinearSnapHelper` and `RecyclerView` item will **snap to the center if you drag it**. This triggers item selection and it will read data from the snapped item.

Problem occurs if data are **empty**.

I create new item as usual by pushing `Button` and it is created successfully. Then my `RecyclerView` contains single Item. So **I have to push that item just by few pixels programatically** to trigger `onScrollStateChangedListener` on my `RecyclerView` to load first item's data.

But this little scroll makes my recyclerView item disappear **RV is empty (IN GUI ONLY)** (data are there, they are selected and everything is fine(programatically)).

I've even added log to `onBindViewHolder()` and it is executed right after `notifyDataSetChanged()` and my `RecyclerView` is still empty in GUI.

If I comment that if statement with scrolling, item will appear in recyclerView with all data loaded, but I have to scroll it (#1 - It will change item's background and #2 - It will load item's data to Singleton variable).

Where is the problem?

ObjectCreationActivity:

```
setObjects(objectsJSONArray)
setResult(REFRESH_CODE)
finish()
```

Fragments parent Activity:

```
if (resultCode == REFRESH_CODE){
            createLog("REFRESH_CODE", "isTrue()")
            if (((pagerAdapter!!.getItem(1)) as ObjectFragment).view != null){
                ((pagerAdapter!!.getItem(1)) as ObjectFragment).refreshFragmentData()
            }
        }
```

Fragment:

```
fun refreshFragmentData(){
        recylerViewAdapter.refreshData()
    }
```

Adapter:

```
   fun refreshData(){
            createLog("Adapter", "Refreshing Data")
            createLog("Adapter", adapterObjectList.toString()) //here it contains 1 item
            adapterObjectList = Singleton.getInstance(fragment.context!!).objectList //Refreshing list for second time to be sure
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            if (adapterObjectList.size == 1){
                recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(5, 0)
            }
        }
```